# What is the computational complexity of finding the number of times a circuit changes value on an exponentially large graph?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, graph-theory

Let C be a circuit that maps n-length bitstrings to elements of {0, 1, 2}.  Imagine ordering the set of n-length bitstrings in a giant loop: 00000 is adjacent to 00001 and 11111; 00001 is adjacent to 00000 and 00010; etc.

If C(00000) = x and C(00001) != x, then C changed value between these adjacent nodes.  I want to count the total number of times that C changes value on the loop; more specifically, I only want to know whether this number is even or odd.

What is the complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

with no additional information on the function (cuircuit) C, I guess you have to just count...
(what you certainly cannot do, is to infer any functional "characteristics" of C by looking at its input-output for only a proper subset of the domain of consideration.)

So, I guess, that you have to perform O(n) many applications of C where n is the size of the "loop"... so, in your case exponential